# Cannot get Applinks to work with dynamically set properties

Tags: angularjs, facebook, applinks

We are currently working on an `Angular` app as a companion for an `IOS` app. We want to integrate `Applinks` in it and the properties to be set dynamically via the controllers. We are using the `hashbang prefix`:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!')
```

When I run the url through *Facebook debugger*, I see all `AppLinks` properties with their right values:

```
<meta property="al:iphone:url" content="myapp://open" />
<meta property="al:iphone:app_store_id" content="myappid" />
<meta property="al:iphone:app_name" content="myapp name" />
<meta property="al:web:url" content="myappweburl" />
```

`myappweburl` is stated in the FB application settings as App Domain.

Problem is that I don't see the 'Open in app' line on the bottom when I click on a custom story, but I see it when I click on a link, shared by the app (both of these have the same web url endpoint and meta). Can anyone help with this?

Comment: How are you publishing your custom stories?

Comment: I am using the FB Open Graph Tool. What I have found out up until now is that if I post OG object with url without #!, the 'Open in app' banner appears opposed to not appearing with urls, containing #!

Comment: we have resolved this now. Problem was that FB app wasn't configured properly and the protocol of the ios url with which it was calling our app was in the format: fb[fb_appid]://